# Custom Webpack wrapper library not installing dependencies

Tags: npm, webpack

I wrote a wrapper library for internal use of webpack with all the needed loaders and config stuff pre-done so I only have to install the wrapper library to every project and add the entry configuration.
So far that worked but for my newest, freshly cloned project it doesn't.

I tried deleting the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file and do a clean `npm i` but it's still the same.

`webpack-cli` is installed, but has `webpack` as peer-dependency and it says it isn't installed. When I add it to the projects' `package.json` it works, but then trying to `npm run build` results in several errors that it couldn't find any of the loaders that should have been installed with the library.

**project package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress --colors --hide-modules",
    "dev": "npm run build --",
    "watch": "npm run dev -- --watch",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production npm run build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@namespace/lib": "git+ssh://git@internal:js/lib.git"
  },
```

**library package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.3.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.4",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.4",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.4.2",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17",
    "webpack": "^4.23.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "standard": "^12.0.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the

```
"@namespace/lib": "git+ssh://git@internal:js/lib.git"
```

line from the projects' `package.json` file and did a

```
npm i -D git+ssh://git@internal:js/lib.git
```

and now it installed all the libraries' dependencies.

Before that I just ran `npm i` from the newly cloned project with the existing lines in the `package.json`. I don't understand why that would make a difference, but it seems it did!

//EDIT:

Another thing that worked:

```
git reset --hard
rm package-lock.json
rm -rf node_modules # deleting already installed modules from the previous tries
npm i
```

So from a fresh `git clone`-perspective it's just deleting the lock-file and *then* installing again. *But without* a pre-existing `node_modules` folder.